# Using erb render in javascripts folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to use a non-controller-connected button to insert a rails partial in a div. As I'm not doing this via the controller, I can't use the standard format.js to do this. The script is placed inside the `assets/javascripts` folder and this is the important code inside of it:

accounts.js.erb:

```
$("#account-div").append("<%= j render("newbutton") %>");
```

When I'm trying to open the site, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc7bd060f8>:0x007fbc7aaa0e40>
```

The code above works when its placed inside the AJAX response via the respond.to block. How can I pass the correct path so that the render method finds the `_newbutton.html.erb` file, which resides inside the `views/accounts/` folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since assets cannot use render method, move your .js.erb files into views directory and use

```
<%= j render(:partial => 'accounts/newbutton') %>
```

Reference - [Rendering partial in js.erb file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127934/rendering-partial-in-js-erb-file) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309970/184184

Comment: forgot, you need to use `:partial`

Comment: views/accounts/newbutton should be accounts/newbutton since accounts is the controller directory

Comment: I think this needs to be checked again

Comment: Still doesn't work. When rendering the same partial with an AJAX response it works. Could the problem be somewhere else?

Comment: read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render

Comment: Hmm, what is the correct way to load the js file from the views directory?

Comment: I think you can place this .js.erb file under /views/accounts and call  from your action view. this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437282/how-to-include-js-erb-file-in-view-folder