# How do I pass a json value into a rails render partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Ok...I am banging my head into hamburger. Is this possible? Am I doing life right?

I have a value called "myValue.id" in a javascript function and I need to pass this value as a variable into a rails partial "new" but I do not know how. This is an old rails 2.3 app any help is appreciated... here is what this looks like....

```
      eventClick: function(myValue, jsEvent, view) {
                        console.log("eventClick function called");
                        console.log("myValue.id "+myValue.id);
                        jQuery('#remote_container').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>"new", :locals=>??????) %>');
                        jQuery('#new_event').modal('show');
                    }
```

Comment: Never rendered partials within js code but I doubt this is possible (unless render method makes another request to the server). The reason for this is that JS is client side and Ruby is server side.
A way to go would be having an AJAX call, rendering new partial at the backend, getting it back at the client side and the displaying it.
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2331203/7956790

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use input text value property to pass your javascript variable to the controller. Firstly just make simple form with hidden input property that have specific id in your `index.html`. Next create button that will send the variable to

```
<form id "myForm" action="/welcome/index">
  <input type="hidden" id="myVar" name="varParams">
</form>
<button id="btnSend">SEND</button>
```

Then, create javascript function to set the value of the input text with our required variable when the button is clicked. Just put below code in your `index.html`.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('btnSend').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById("myVar").value = "myValue";
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
</script>
```

Next, just retrieve the myVar params in your `welcome_controller.rb`.

```
  def index
    myVar = params[:varParams]
    # Do something with myVar variable  
  end
```

Just modify the code provided to fulfill your needs.